# How to change dialog title based on button id in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to be able to change the JQuery dialog title (as well as other things) based on which button is clicked on the page.

I have several button with all the same class and each one has a different id. Whenever any button is clicked, it will open the dialog box.  I am not sure if the if statement syntax is correct as I am quite new to JQuery.

```
 $(function(){
    $(".dialogButtons").click(function(){

        if($(this).attr('id') == "button1"){

            $("#dialog-form").dialog('option', 'title', 'title for button one');

        }

        $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
    });
```

I wanted to leave the orginal question but I did figure out how to find out which id is clicked.

```
$(this).is("#button1")
```

I still have not figured out how to change the title although I did try this as well but it didn't work:

```
 $("#dialog-form").attr('title', 'Button one title');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your buttons `data` attribute and pull the text from it, instead of writing `if` statement for each button separately.

Try this one:

**button**: (assuming it's a button)

```
<button class="dialogButtons" data-title="some title">Button 1</button>
<button class="dialogButtons" data-title="another title">Button 2</button>
```

**script**:

```
 $(function(){

     $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        // other options...
     });

     $(".dialogButtons").click(function(){
         var title = $(this).data('title');
         $("#dialog-form").dialog('option', 'title', title);
         $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
     });

});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/yyf5Lp01/)**

Comment: I will also need to populate a select list based on which button is clicked. Would I be able to do that with this solution rather than using if statements?

Comment: Difficult to say. It could be possible, but all depends on what you need achieve exactly.